# How does Vim display macros in registers?

Tags: vim, macros, keyboard

I found out how handy it is to be able to use macros in Vim. In particular recording with `q` but I'm confused about how to read what is stored in the register I'm recording to.

To take a specific example, I use Vim a lot for writing LaTeX documents, and in that connection I have made a macro that puts a `%` at the start of the current line, so that this code is commented out. I did this by recording as follows. I pressed the keys `q` `u` <kbd>Home</kbd> `i` `%` <kbd>Esc</kbd> `q`. Now by pressing `@u` I am able to play that macro, and since I use that one a lot I decided to put it in my `.vimrc` file. I looked at the subject and found out that I have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to grab the keystrokes I use, e.g., the escape key. I

```
let @u='^[OHi%^['
```

where I produced `^OH` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Home</kbd> and `^[` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd>. Now when I start Vim the contents of register `u` is `^[OHi%^[`, as it ought to be, but if I just recorded the macro with `q`, then the register would read

```
<80>khi%^[
```

I have tried to understand what this means. It does the same thing, but if I try to write something similar using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> after consulting some of the help pages in Vim (more precisely `:help key-notation`, `:help i_CTRL-V` and `:help i_CTRL-V_digit`), but I still don't understand it.

My motivation for wanting to understand this is that I would like to be able to read what a macro I have recorded does. If I understand how the contents of the register is produced, then I might be able to understand it by producing a similar result. For example if the macros I recorded followed the same syntax as when using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then I could just check what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> plus the most likely keystrokes produced and see which one matches.

Comment: not a answer to your question, but you should try to use use `0` instead of `<home>`. That would save you a `ctrl-v`.

Comment: while it's honorable to try it by yourself: I think the Nerd Commenter also supports LaTeX: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think a macro is the right tool for the job and I think that you really should follow `$ vimtutor` right now: `<Home>i%<Esc>` is not the right way to insert a `%` at the beginning of the line.

```
nnoremap <leader>% I%<Esc>
```

seems to be a better and more correct solution.

`<80>xx` is a control character used internally by Vim to represent special keys. See `$ man termcap` for a list of possible values.

Comment: I'm not that experienced as a Vim user, so I don't know if a macro is not the best way to do it, but the reason that I use a macro is that it alows me to type `:'<,'>normal @u` which then puts a `%` at the beginning of each line in visual. Besides that I actually started with the `I%<Esc>` solution, but if your line starts with a number of `<Tab>`'s then the `%` is places after the `<Tab>`'s and I would like to avoid that. Is it possible to produce this control character yourself?

Comment: `:'<,'>norm I%` works too or `:'<,'>norm 0i%` if you wat your `%` at column 1. The whole macro business is useless here, IMO. I don't know how you could input that `<80>kc` notation. Maybe you could save this `<80>` in  a register and paste it before the correct termcap notation for the key you want to emulate. I have the feeling that going through all that is not very useful.

Comment: I guess you are right. I think I will drop trying to find out how to produce these. I don't need it. If I want to decode the macro I recorded I can consult `$ man termcap`. And thanks for the hint on the use of `norm`. Moments when I realize a thing like that are moments where I realize how incredably much I love using Vim. It is definitely made by people who know how a text editing program ought to work.

Comment: Indeed. [Check this out](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eX9m3g5J-XA) if you haven't already ([slightly older text version](http://www.moolenaar.net/habits.html)).